# run bash script file (test.sh) from R with system2('test.sh')

Tags: r

let's say I have a bash file

```
#test.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "hello from bash"
```

and I want to call that file from R file `call.R`

```
# call.R
system2('test.sh')
```

when I do this I got error `CreateProcess' failed to run` .
How can I run a custom bash script file from R script?

Comment: The _first two characters of the file_ need to be `#!` -- you can't put a line with a comment like `#test.sh` before it. Also, qualify your path -- `./test.sh` if the file is in the working directory (UNIX systems don't search the working directory for executables by default for security reasons) -- and make sure the file has +x permissions. (And make sure that if you're assuming that the working directory and the directory with the source code match, that that assumption is actually true).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I put this `#test.sh` just to show the file name, that not in the file.
I can run the file with `./test.sh`. both file in the same directory.
 And I put this directory in the $PATH too. still I get error 

 ```
sh: 1: test.sh: not found
Warning message:
In system2("test.sh") : error in running command

Comment: As I said before, the `./` needs to be used in the `system2()` call. That is to say, it should be `system2("./test.sh")`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. 
Yes, when  I put `./` in the `system2()` it works. Thank You so much.

Comment: (as a separate master, executables shouldn't have extensions -- you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`; and `pip`, not `pip.py`; use the `.sh` when writing POSIX shell _libraries_, not executable scripts).